# hide 2 li's in a ul on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am attempting to hide the first two list items when my site goes down to mobile. I have added a class on each li i want to hide and then attempt a media query and display none in the css. However it doesnt seem to be working. Here is my code

```
<ul class="home-btns btns-3 center">
    <li class="hide-mobile">
        <a href="/why-attend/"><span class="welcome-robot center"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/assets/images/robot-icon-welcome.png" alt="Robot Icon" /></span> <span class="btn-text">Why Attend?</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="hide-mobile">
        <a href="/agenda/"><span class="fa fa-group center"></span> <span class="btn-text">Agenda</span></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/#pass-section"><span class="fa fa-ticket center"></span> <span class="btn-text">Register Now</span></a>
    </li>
</ul>

@media screen and (max-width: 667px) {
     .hide-mobile {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming that you have the meta viewport configured, the mediaqueries in the correct order and the CSS out of this HTML block, maybe your problem is that your device is larger than 667 pixels width.

Comment: Some mobile devices have a screen wider than 667px

Comment: I suspect you're having a specificity problem. Do you have any other css that would be applied to these li's? Can you use the chrome inspector to adjust the viewport width down to this breakpoint and see what css is being applied to the li's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say what it could be without seeing your wider code to check it's all in order (viewport meta tag, etc).

Instead of assigning a custom class to the first 2 li's, why don't you try using the nth-child selectors for a more programmatic approach:

```
@media (max-width: 667px) {
  ul.home-btns li:nth-child(1), ul.home-btns li:nth-child(2) {
    display: none
  }
}
```

Comment: True, but I can't comment on the issue without seeing all pieces of the puzzle. Thought I'd provide a tip in good faith in the interim :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine, see http://codepen.io/nicholasabrams/pen/YyOerE. Resize the preview window and watch your LIs disappear

```
     <ul class="home-btns btns-3 center">
                <li class="hide-mobile">
                    <a href="/why-attend/"><span class="welcome-robot center"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/assets/images/robot-icon-welcome.png" alt="Robot Icon" /></span> <span class="btn-text">Why Attend?</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="hide-mobile">
                    <a href="/agenda/"><span class="fa fa-group center"></span> <span class="btn-text">Agenda</span></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/#pass-section"><span class="fa fa-ticket center"></span> <span class="btn-text">Register Now</span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>

@media screen and (max-width: 667px) {
     .hide-mobile {
    display:none;
  }
}
```